# window.opener return Cross Origin error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain, window.open, window.opener

I already developed application to open popup using below code,

```
var url = 'child.html';
var args = ['value'];
var options='height:150px;width:300px'
window.openModalDialog(url,args,options);
```

Am able to read argument from openModalDialog using below code

```
var args = window.dialogArguments;
var arg = args[0];
```

Now am migrating application to Chrome. As per document **window.openModalDialog** not supported in Chrome.
So, I plan to replace it with **window.open**. Now am facing issue when I try to get argument.
Because, am unable to get argument using **window.dialogArguments**. 
I tried with

```
window.opener and parent.window.opener
```

to get argument. It return Cross Origin error.
how can I get arguments from **window.open**.?

Answer (score 1):

With `window.open` you should save the opener into a variable, and then you can access the arguments.

```js
var url = 'child.html';
var args = ['value'];
var options='height:150px;width:300px'
let newWindow = window.open(url,args,options);
```

And the arguments will be inside `newWindow.location` object.

> ***NOTE:*** This WILL NOT work if your window opens in a different domain, since that tries to break a security policy called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Thank you @k3llydev. Am opening window in same origin, parent window url is **http://localhost:8080/project/result** and Child window - window.open url is **http://localhost:8080/project/popup.** Still am getting CROS error, how to ensure that I am opening window in same domain.?

Comment: You are in the same origin, which is `localhost`. Try returning the following header in your `localhost:8080/project/popup` path: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Lately, you can replace * with the domain you are going to use in production: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com`.